# Deserialization of dynamic attribute of JSON entity using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

There is JSON entity that has `value` dynamic attribute:

```
   {
    "name" : "name1",
    "value" : {"different structures: strings, enums, arrays, custom entities"}
   }
```

Java representation of the entity:

```
public class Entity {
    public String name;
    public Object value;
}
```

In `value` can be passed completely different JSON structures. Every time `value` should be mapped to different POJOs.

Is there any common approach to deserialize `value` attribute to particular entities except additional deserializing of the `value` attribute content (`Map<String, String>` structure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to know the exact type to what I should deserialize `value` new attribute `valueType` should be added. 
Additionally, custom deserializer should be implemented to handle deserialization to the desired type.

`Entity` class is extended with `valueType` and `@JsonDeserialize` annotation:

```
public class Entity {
    public String name;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = EntityValueDeserializer.class)
    public Object value;
    public Class valueType;
}
```

JSON is changed correspondingly:

```
   {
    "name" : "name1",
    "value" : "some string" | 10 | "any custom entity",
    "valueType" : "java.lang.String" | "java.lang.Integer" | "any custom type"
   }
```

Then implement custom deserializer `EntityValueDeserializer` that gets `valueType` and proceed deserialization of `value` to `valueType`:

```
public class EntityValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object>
{

   public Object deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException
   {
      ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
      JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
      Entity entity = ((Entity) jp.getParsingContext().getCurrentValue());
      return codec.treeToValue(node, entity.valueType);
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used either `@JsonSubTypes` (serialize into different types) or `@JsonDeserialize` (custom serialization) to do this. You can see some examples at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: But @JsonSubTypes is not suitable for completely different classes without common hierarchy.

Comment: Your answer helps me to find the right solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can ALWAYS deserialize any valid JSON document into class `Map<String, Object>` you don't have to do "additional" deserialization. Just change your `public Object value;` into `public Map<String, Object> value;` and it should work.

Comment: I completely agree that this solution works but, in that case, I should map `Map<String, Object> value` to my server-side model after deserialization. I want to shift this responsibility to Jackson in some way.

Comment: So you change your Entity class to have a value as Map<String, Object> and make Entity class as a parameter of your end-point method on the server-side. Then you send your JSON to your server-side and it gets deserialized into your Entity class automatically. And then you have your Entity class instance on your server-side. Do I miss anything?

Comment: But I don't understand how it helps to deserialize `value` that can contain different types into a given model? After deserialization it will be `Map<String, Object>` but I want to get `Integer` or `Boolean` or some custom entity inside `value` attribute.